# How to use Tailwind color with custom utility class?

Tags: tailwind-css

Similar to how Tailwind does `border-l` and `border-blue-200`, how could I do this with a custom utility class? Eg. `custom custom-blue-200`.

At the moment I have a utility class defined like this:

```
@layer utilities {
    .corner-cut {
         background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 10px);
    }
}
```

This has been working fine, but now I need to combine these with a color parameter in order to make the rgb part of the gradient not hard-coded to one color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a plugin that defines a [dynamic utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities):

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
const flattenColorPalette = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette').default
const { parseColor } = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/color')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'corner-cut': (value) => {
            const { color } = parseColor(value)

            return {
              backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, rgba(${color[0]} ${color[1]} ${color[2]} / 0.9) 10px`,
            }
          },
        },
        { values: flattenColorPalette(theme('colors')), type: 'color' },
      )
    }),
  ]
}
```

You can then combine the class with a custom colour, e.g. `corner-cut-blue-200`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `!important` to the end of each declaration yourself:

```
@layer utilities {
  .corner-cut {
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 10px) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: The colour needs to come from the class and not be hard-coded. Important isn't needed as it was already working.